# What are unusual ports?

Tags: security, transport-protocol, ddos

I found the unusual ports at 2 places, maybe one has got the idea from the other without acknowledging it.

Hi,
I am trying to understand mismatch port application. I am reading the article:

https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/threat-hunting-for-mismatched-port-application-traffic/
The article says that :

```
Ports numbers vary from 0-65535, In which port 0-1023 are system ports or well-known ports, port 1024-49151 are user port or registered ports and port 49151 to 65535 are dynamic ports or private ports. If an application is using an unusual port which pretends to be a normal application port, then it indicates a sign of compromise.
```

But I can’t understand what is meant by unusual port?

However, the following article says that: DDoS Cyber-Incident Detection in Smart Grids,

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358905792_DDoS_Cyber-Incident_Detection_in_Smart_Grids

```
Mismatch in Port-Application. If the data are being sent from unusual ports, a
malicious attack could be occurring
```

Again I can’t understand what is meant by unusual port. Are these standards ports like port 80?

I understand that in networking applications we have port numbers to identify applications. We need the port number and IP address to communicate with the application. So if port# 80 is already used by HTTP server how can it become an unusual port? If an attacker tries to use it, we will have a conflict in this case. Please guide me on what is meant by unusual port.
Zulfi.

Comment: Using a port that is registered for one thing to send traffic for something else. Not all hosts/servers are running an HTTP server, so an application could use port 80 for something else. Only when an application on a host/server has claimed a transport protocol port for itself is the port unavailable to other applications. Also, TCP and UDP ports are not the same port, even if they have the same number. TCP port 12345 is not UDP port 12345.

Comment: @RonMaupin, thanks, how can we identify that an application is using a standard port number, say port 21, but it is not functioning in that manner, while we are in a DDoS attack?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers and applications are off-topic here. You could ask about things like that on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, "unusual port" refers to a port number used in an application that is *not* that application protocol's well-known port. E.g. HTTP's usual ports are 80, 8080 (alternative) and 443 (HTTPS). Running a web server on some other port is *unusual*. Of course, any client would need to use whatever port the server is listening on in order to connect.

While the first linked article points out that connections with unusual ports show a security problem or compromise, that isn't necessarily the case - it is only when you know the host and it's not normally using those ports. At the same time, a connection using a well-known port to a compromised host looks innocent but may be dangerous all the same. Essentially, port numbers *may* be a sign for something odd, but in reality there is some much more to it.

The second link is about something else. For amplified DDoS attacks, third-party hosts are coaxed into generating traffic towards the attacked network. That traffic *originates* from well-known ports, not the expected client ephemeral ports, or vice versa. Relating between a datagram's source and destination ports may help filtering malicious traffic at the perimeter.

Note that applications, application-layer protocols and servers are explicitly off topic here, so we cannot dive into that much more.

Comment: Sorry, why is it necessary that 3rd party host generate traffic from well-known ports? Bots have to send requests to the targeted server, I can't understand why they specifically use well-known ports. What if well-known is not available?

Comment: That technique is used in an *amplified* DDoS attack. *Some* traffic is sent to 3rd-party hosts, causing them to sent *a lot* of traffic to the target.